# Window.open opens new tab in safari when maximized

Tags: javascript, html, safari, window.open

One safari browser window is already open through the `Window.open(1st)` and from that `window`,on clicking a button,the callback opens another `window(2nd)` with a link to outside domain. 
Safari opens the outside link in new browser window if the 1st browser window is not maximized , but when the 1st browser window is maximized then outside URL opens in the adjacent tab instead of new browser window.

How do I make the safari browser open the new browser window when the 1st browser window is maximized as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled over a similar issue and found out that this is related to a setting for the Dock.

> Click the “Prefer tabs when opening documents” pop-up menu, then choose an option—Always, In Full Screen Only, or Manually. By default, documents open in tabs only when an app is full screen.
>   ~ https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25079?locale=en_US

I set it to `Manually` and now it opens a new window for the popup when I am in fullscreen mode.
However be aware that the popup will also be in fullscreen mode!